# Parse errors in do-blocks

Tags: haskell

When I try to load the following code to ghci

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import System.IO

interactWith function inputFile outputFile = do
  input <- readFile inputFile

writeFile outputFile (function input)
main = mainWith myFunction
  where mainWith function = do
    args <- getArgs
    case args of
    [input,output] -> interactWith function input output
    _ -> putStrLn "error: exactly two arguments needed"
                                                             
myFunction = id
```

it produces `error: parse error on input ‘args’`. But it is not clear to me what is producing the problem, and I am unable to divine what the problem is by looking at the answers to questions on parse errors.

Why is an error produced?

Comment: Indent the `args <- ...` at least one column more to the right than the start of `mainWith function = ...`.

Comment: This then throws ``error: parse error on input ‘->’``.

Comment: yes, because that needs to be indented at least one column more to the right than the start of `case args of`... Haskell is just like Python an indentation sensitive language.

Comment: Indenting the two lines below ``case args of`` to the right still produces ``error: parse error on input ‘->’``

Comment: I then tried to put the case arguments of ``case args of`` further to the right of ``of`` and it produced ``Parse error: module header, import declaration
    or top-level declaration expected.``, citing ``writeFile outputFile (function input)``.

Comment: since the `writeFile outputFile (function input)` is part of the `do` block, it needs to be indented at the same level of `input <- ...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fix the indentation of your program. The items under the `do` block should be indented at least one column more to the right than the start of the definition in the `where` clause. You should also indent the cases under the `case … of` clause:

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import System.IO

interactWith function inputFile outputFile = do
    input <- readFile inputFile
    writeFile outputFile (function input)

main = mainWith myFunction
  where mainWith function = do
            args <- getArgs
            case args of
                [input,output] -> interactWith function input output
                _ -> putStrLn "error: exactly two arguments needed"
                                                             
myFunction = id
```